# Setting imageviewresource from gallery

Tags: java, android, image

I've got a program, where I have SQLite database. In one table, one of column store Integer values, which are "adresses" to image in drawable. (when i want to add one row I use method: `recipesBase.newRecipe("BakedOmelet", "Breakfast","Description2", R.drawable.i024, recipe_1, steps_1);`, where recipesBase is an instance of class extends from **SQLiteOpenHelper** and this column take value **R.drawable.i024**. All works well, but now I have to take some data from user, and one of its is image from gallery. I put it into a ImageView:

```
JavaIntent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
```

and:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.img);
                img.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                //

                String savedImageURL = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                        getContentResolver(),
                        selectedImage,
                        "Image",
                        "UserData"
                );

                // Parse the gallery image url to uri
                Uri savedImageURI = Uri.parse(savedImageURL);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), savedImageURL, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You haven't picked Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

then when I have it loaded to ImageView, I want to create new row in my SQLite table, and as you can guess, one of the values in it should be "address" of this image. How can I do this? Is that even a good what I am doing, or only very complicated way of doing something simple?

Comment: you have `imageUri` - simply pass it to `ImageView#setImageURI` method

Comment: But can I use it in ImageView.setImageResource method?

Comment: what for? `Uri` is not a resource - its `Uri` - why do you need to call `setImageResource `?

Comment: Becouse, in another activity, I need to be able to create ListView with ImageView And TextView in each item. To do this i use Image Resources

Comment: Okej, tylko jak mam "wziąć" `Uri` Plików w folderze drawable?
Ok, but how can I get the `Uri` of images in Drawable folder?

Comment: inside `onActivityResult` in your return `Intent` you call `Intent#getData()` - this is your `Uri` - read more about `Uri` - `ContentResolver` official documenation

Comment: i mean `ContentResolver#SCHEME_*`, and you will see that there are couple of types of `Uri`s, just find all the places with `SCHEME_`, powodzenia